# C#: Why is my Process that is running Java.exe working perfectly, but the window isn't returning ANY output?

Tags: c#, process

I created a Process that is targeted to the Java.exe file. The process should run a Java.jar server file, and continue to run giving output feedback until the server crashed or I forcefully close it down. Everything works fine.. the server is running.. and when I set UseShellExecute to True I can see the black CMD window returning all the output. But when I set it to false and redirect the output... the Window is completely blank ( the server is still running though ) and the OutputDataReceived event doesn't fire at all ( I think I got it to once but that was when I closed the window it seemed the args was empty ) and as far as I can see StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() isnt returning anything either. Why is this Process not returning any Output feedback?? Here is my code:

```
    gameServerProcess = new Process();
    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    gameServerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    gameServerProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(gameServer_WindowExit);

    window = new ServerWindow();
    gameServerProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(window.server_recievedOutputStream);
    window.Show();

    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\java.exe";
    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Users\Zack\Desktop\ServerFiles\gameserver";
    gameServerProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-Xmx1024m -cp ./../libs/*;l2jserver.jar net.sf.l2j.gameserver.GameServer";
    gameServerProcess.Start();
    gameServerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

And my 'window' form class code which should receive the DataReceivedEventArgs with the output data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MWRemoteServer
{
    public partial class ServerWindow : Form
    {
        private delegate void WriteOutputDelegate(string output);
        private WriteOutputDelegate writeOutput;

        public ServerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            logBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            logBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            writeOutput = new WriteOutputDelegate(write);
        }

        public void server_recievedOutputStream(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Called window output!");
            if (args.Data != null)
            {
                BeginInvoke(writeOutput, new object[] { args.Data.ToString() });
            }
        }

        private void write(string output)
        {
            logBox.AppendText(output + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Again the process works completely fine and with the UseShellExecute set to true I can see it is providing all information I need to grab. But when I set that to false its blank and I cant seem to grab any output data!

Thank you so much in advance...  I've been at this for hours and hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it writes to stdout? Have you tried checking stderr? (`RedirectStandardError`/`StandardError`/`ErrorDataReceived`/`BeginErrorReadLine`).

If it writes directly to the display buffer (instead of stderr/stdout) then it might not be possible without a **lot** of work.

Comment: OMFG It seems it was writing to the stderr ??? Why in the heck would it do that for its called 'Standard' 'Output' for a REASON! Thank you !